# kendo chart- column - setOptions not changing series labels

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I've got a page full of charts, and we want to be able to open them up in a larger size. Which means changing the font sizes for all the text in the chart.  It's working quite well, except for the SERIES labels.

I've tried setting (and resetting) them in seriesDefaults, and also, in the series, but neither have worked out. valueAxis and categoryAxis labels are doing what I ask, so I'm not real sure where I'm going wrong with the series labels.

I've created a dojo, here: https://dojo.telerik.com/oYiXaL/9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why your code is not working, but setting the properties directly seems to work:

```
$(".expand").on("click", function(){
  var chartBoss = $(this).data("boss");

  $("#bigChart").kendoChart($(chartBoss).data("kendoChart").options);
  var chart = $("#bigChart").data("kendoChart");
  chart.options.series[0].labels.font = "20px BrandonGrotesqueWeb-Bold";
  chart.options.valueAxis.labels.font = "28px BrandonGrotesqueWeb-Regular";
  chart.options.categoryAxis.labels.font = "24px BrandonGrotesqueWeb-Medium";

  $(".big").show();
});
```